# React router - find current route in flux store

Tags: reactjs, react-router, reactjs-flux, react-native-router-flux

I am using react router with flux. Is there any way to know the current route in an store? I tried using `this.props.location.pathname` but it is always undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Since last version (v4) you can access to your app navigations state as simple as **Actions.state**, use **Actions.currentScene** to get name of current scene.

You can see more details on GitHub https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux